Can I take the derivative of only part of a function when solving for its maximum or minimum?
Let me illustrate my point with a simple example.
Suppose we want to find the maximum of $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ (assuming all functions are differentiable), where differentiating $g(x)$  is straightforward but $h(x)$ is very complicated. If we additionally know that $h(x)$ is bounded within $[M,N]$, we can solve for $x^*$ that maximizes $g(x)$ and conclude that $\max f(x)\in[g(x^*)+M,g(x^*)+N]$.
I am encountering a similar function:
$$f(x)=\beta x(1-a)[a-h(x)]+g(x),x>0$$
where $g^\prime(x)$ is trivial but $h^\prime(x)$ is messy. But $h(x)$ is bounded within $[0,\tilde{h}(x)]$ where $\tilde{h}(x)$ is decreasing quickly in $x$ and $\tilde{h}(x)>0$.
My question is: When solving for the maximum or minimum of $f(x)$, can I avoid differentiating $h(x)$ and instead treat it as an unknown constant within $[0,H]$.

You can do what you suggest, but you may not get the maximum value of $f(x)$.  Your first paragraph is correct in that the maximum of $f(x)$ is in that range, but it may not occur at $x^*$ because $h(x^*)$ may be on the small side and there is another $x^{**}$ where $h(x^{**})$ is quite large and $g(x^{**})$ is not much smaller than $g(x^{*})$.
In the second, you need to bound the whole first term, not just $h(x)$ to apply the same approach.  From what you have given $\beta$ might be very large and the first term could be dominant.
